# Linux Perl TK: How to know if the window of my script is the active window or not?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a Perl script using TK for gui, I just need to know upon calling it and during the time its active if it is still the "ACTIVE WINDOW" on your screen.

I want it to commit suicide(exit or die) if its no longer the "ACTIVE WINDOW" on your screen.

Example 1: I executed it, normally, its the active window, so nothing will happen.
Example 2: While its active, I clicked another gui application, so my current script is not ACTIVE WINDOW on my screen anymore, so now it must commit suicide and kill itself.

Comment: Why is this too broad?  It is asking a specific question in a specific case.

Comment: Well, since the people listed above don't understand your question, I can't create an answer.  One method that might work is to do a `bind . <Leave> exit`.   When the cursor leaves the primary window, the application will exit.  This will work well if your primary windows receives the focus and mouse cursor is in your primary window upon startup.

Comment: @BradLanam can you remove the HOLD if possible? So I can answer my own question.

Comment: I can't remove the hold.  I flagged the question with a note hoping to get a moderator to fix it, but no luck.

Comment: But still, thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 2):

The method GetInputFocus in package [GUITest](http://search.cpan.org/~ctrondlp/X11-GUITest-0.28/GUITest.pm) will tell you witch window has the keyboard focus.